# nginx permission denied while reading upstream - even when run as root

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app running under uWSGI behind nginx.

```
*1 readv() failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 10.0.3.1, server: , request: "GET /some/path/constants.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/uwsgi.sock:", host: "dev.myhost.com"
```

The permissions on the socket are okay (666, and set to the same user as nginx), in fact, even when I run nginx as root I still get this error.

The flask app/uwsgi is sending the request properly. But it's just not being read by Nginx. This is on Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn.

Any idea *where* the permission might be getting denied if the nginx process has full access to the socket?

As a complicating factor this server is running in a container that has Ubuntu 14.04 installed in it. And this setup used to work... but I recently upgraded the host to 14.10... I can fully understand that this could be the cause of the problem. But before I downgrade the host or upgrade the container I want to understand why.

When I run strace on a worker that's generating this error I see the call it's making is something like this:

```
readv(14, 0x7fffb3d16a80, 1)            = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

`14` seems to be the file descriptor created by this system call

```
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 14
```

So it can't read from a local socket that it has just created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay! So the problem was, I think, related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1390223). It seems that even though apparmor wasn't configured to prevent access to sockets inside the containers it was actually doing something to prevent reading from them (though not creation...) so turning off apparmor for the container ([following these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-apparmor)) worked to fix it.

The two relevant lines were:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.lxc-start
```

sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.lxc-start /etc/apparmor.d/disabled/

and adding

```
lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
```

To the containers config file.

NB: These errors were not recorded in any apparmor logs.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the fix? Does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: I've added the two relevant line to my answer. But if those aren't fixing the problem for you then you may have an unrelated issue :(

Comment: Unfortunately there's no usr.bin.lxc-start file on my system, there's only /etc/apparmor.d/docker. And when I do the described procedure with docker file the docker service does not start anymore with `Error response from daemon: Cannot start container database: set apparmor profile docker-default: no such file or directory
FATA[0000] Error: failed to start one or more containers`

Comment: @aychedee May I know where's the config file? Ae we supposed to edit the config file manually or run certain lxc cmd to edit? I suspect I'm hit by the same bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969166/nginx-permission-denied-while-reading-upstream-even-when-run-as-root?rq=1

Comment: I just edited the container's config file manually. It is in the containers directory: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man5/lxc.conf.5.html

Answer (score 1):

This problem was probably introduced in kernel 3.16, because it does not reproduce on 14.04 with 3.13 kernel. Strange apparmor bug was indeed responsible for that.

Unfortunately @aychedee's solution didn't work for me. In my case I had to add the following parameter to `docker run` command to get rid of the issue:

```
docker run --security-opt apparmor:unconfined ...
```

If someone's aware what is the current state of the issue, please consider adding comment under this answer :)

Comment: The main difference is that you're using docker, while I was using linux containers. Same problem, but different container tech so the config is in a different place.